# Question about Rearrangement of Absolutely convergent Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

> Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is an absolutely convergent series and let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a bijective map. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{f(n)}$
>   is absolutely convergent and has the same limit $L$.

I was reading this and I was a little unclear as to what this was saying. Is this statement saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{f(n)} = L$, or is it saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{f(n)}| = L$? Because I can prove the former and I can show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{f(n)}|$ converges but I don't know whether this statement is saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{f(n)}| = L$ as well.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum a_{f(n)}$ converges to the same value. All we can say regarding the sum of the absolute values is: $\sum|a_n|\geq\sum a_n$...they may have the same value (if $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$), or the values might be different.

Comment: Thanks Clayton, that was the clarification I was looking for because the wording confused me a little.

Comment: It's saying that with the absolute convergence, any rearrangement of the order of summation wouldn't modify the value of the summation.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|<+\infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = L$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{f(n)}=L.$

Answer (score 0):

This says that it is given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = L < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| = M < \infty$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{f(n)} = L$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{f(n)}| = M$.

In short, arbitrary rearrangement of the terms of an absolutely convergent series does not alter the convergence of the series.  (This is automatic for (absolutely) convergent series having only nonnegative terms, such as the two series having value $M$ above.)

Comment: But L is not necessarily equal to M?

Comment: right, $L$ is not necessarily equal to $M$

Comment: I would be explicit in saying $M<+\infty. \qquad$

Comment: @HenryBrown : You see instantly that $L$ is not equal to $M$ unless $a_n\ge0$ for all $n,$ by considering an example: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \tfrac {-1} 2\right)^n. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy : I suppose the Question *is* tagged real analysis.  (I would not do so for one merely tagged calculus and/or sequences and series.)

Answer (score 0):

It is saying the following. Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} a_n$ converges absolutely, and that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} a_n = L.
$$
Then $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} a_{f(n)}$ converges absolutely, and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} a_{f(n)} = L.
$$
There are therefore two things to prove, but the proofs are essentially the same.